# React: do something while all components are mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mount

As in title: how can I do something while all components are mounted in React? I'd like to run script which needs all my components to be mounted.

Comment: You could have a counter in your index file that's incremented by each component in the `componentDidMount`. Each component would check the counter value vs total, and run a function when they match. But I'm don't think this is how React was designed to be used. If you give us more background, maybe we can provide alternatives.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I was thinking that maybe there's some clean way to do that.

Comment: you can place your code in `componentDidMount` since it's called *after* your component (and its children) was mounted.

Comment: @JavierP Ah I didn't realize that `componentDidMount` waits for children as well. That makes it much simpler.

Comment: @sidney Yeah pretty sure it does, I hope it matches your requirements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`React` knows to mount first all `child` components before calling `componentDidMount` on the parent `component`.

So, you can use `componentDidMount` callback method in your main `component`.

As soon as the `render` method has been executed,  the `componentDidMount` function is called. The `DOM` can be accessed in this method, enabling to define `DOM` manipulations or data fetching operations.